# Counting function for Fibonacci numbers

Tags: number-theory, fibonacci-numbers

Are there some results about "Fibonacci-counting function" - the function counting the number of Fibonacci numbers less than or equal to some real number x?

Comment: I'm not too sure, but I would think that [these ideas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Computation_by_rounding) could be used for constructing your function.

Comment: @Sp3000: The method you suggest is right, it is now a matter of setting the expression equal to $x$, taking the logarithm of both sides, and fiddling a bit with floor function. I suggest that you write it up as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to all!   Maybe the answer is (achille hui's version): $$\pi_F(x)=\left\lfloor\log_{\phi}\sqrt{5} \ \left(\lfloor x\rfloor+\frac12\right)\right\rfloor, \ x\geq2 $$

Comment: This can't be right. $F_n$ is alternatively smaller and bigger than $\sqrt{5}\phi^n$. This means the place your $\pi_F(x)$ jumps is alternatively smaller and bigger than corresponding Fibonacii numbers and $\pi_F(F_n) - n = 0$ or $-1$ instead of a constant.

Comment: @achille is correct: this isn’t quite right. For $x=8$, for instance, $\log_\varphi\sqrt5 x\approx5.993536209422$, so the floor is $5$, but $\pi_F(8)=6$. In general it’s going to be too small when $x=F_{2n}$.

Comment: Well thanks, you're rigth! How about latest version?

Comment: Aside from the issue whether you want to count 1 twice, the latest version now looks correct. At least the relation $\pi_F(F_n) = n$ and $\pi_F(F_n-1) = n-1$ now seems to hold for $n \ge 3$.

Comment: @achillehui I think condition $\pi_{F}(F_n-1) = n-1$ is too strong, so here is final version.

Comment: It’s a very good try, but I can prove that no function of this type can agree with $\pi_F$ on all of $\Bbb R^+$; the argument is too long for a comment, so I’ve made it into an ‘answer’.

Comment: As long as the function works on $\mathbb{Z}_{+}$, there is nothing from stopping one doing the obvious by taking one extra floor. i.e $\pi_{F}(x)$ becomes $\lfloor \log_{\phi}(\sqrt{5}\left(\lfloor x \rfloor + 1/2 \right)\rfloor$.

Comment: If one doesn't want nested floor, following formula also seems to work: $$\pi_F(x) =
\left\lfloor \log_{\phi^2}\left( \frac{\sqrt{5}x + \sqrt{5x^2+4}}{2} \right)\right\rfloor
+ \left\lfloor \log_{\phi^2}\left( \frac{\sqrt{5}x + \sqrt{5x^2-4}}{2} \right) + \frac12\right\rfloor$$

Answer (score 2):

The function $\pi_F(x)$ cannot have the form found in lesobrod’s answer. The argument is too long for a comment, so I’ve made it into an ‘answer’, but of course it doesn’t actually answer the original question.

Let $\widehat\varphi=-\frac1\varphi$, the other root of $x^2-x-1=0$. We know that $$F_n=\frac{\varphi^n-\widehat\varphi^n}{\sqrt5}\;,$$ so $$\log_\varphi\left(\sqrt5F_n+\widehat\varphi^n\right)=n\;.$$

Fix $a\in\Bbb R$, and consider the function

$$f(x)=\log_\varphi\left(\sqrt5x+a\right)\;.$$

If $a\le 0$, then $\left\lfloor f(F_{2n})\right\rfloor<2n$, since $\sqrt5F_{2n}+a<\sqrt5F_{2n}+\widehat\varphi^{2n}=\varphi^{2n}$. Thus, we may assume that $a>0$. Since $\widehat\varphi^n\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$,

$$\epsilon_n=\frac{a-\widehat\varphi^{2n}}{\sqrt5}>0$$

for all sufficiently large $n$.

Let $x=F_{2n}-\epsilon_n$; then $a-\sqrt5\epsilon_n=\widehat\varphi^{2n}$, and

$$2n=\log_\varphi\left(\sqrt5F_{2n}+\widehat\varphi^{2n}\right)=\log_\varphi\left(\sqrt5\left(F_{2n}-\epsilon_n\right)+a\right)=f(x)=\left\lfloor f(x)\right\rfloor\;,$$

but $\pi_F(x)\le 2n-1$, since $x<F_{2n}$.

For suitable values of $a$ such a function can agree with $\pi_F$ on $\Bbb Z^+$, but not on all of $\Bbb R^+$.

Comment: Wow It's a real shock!

Comment: How do we know $$\log_\varphi\left(\sqrt5F_n+\widehat\varphi^n\right)=n\;.$$ ?

and the recurrence before it?

Comment: @JiaoCtagon: There is no **recurrence** before it, but if you mean the first displayed formula, it’s [Binet’s formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_sequence#Closed-form_expression), a basic, well-known result. Now rewrite it as $\sqrt5 F_n+\widehat\varphi^n=\varphi^n$ and take logs base $\varphi$ on both sides.